# Loop through and plot columns of two identical dataframes

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, apply

I have two dataframes I'd like to plot against each other:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(HV = c(3,3,3), NAtlantic850t = c(0.501, 1.373, 1.88), AO = c(-0.0512, 0.2892, 0.0664))

> df2 <- data.frame(HV = c(3,3,2), NAtlantic850t = c(1.2384, 1.3637, -0.0332), AO = c(-0.5915, -0.0596, -0.8842))
```

They're identical, I'd like to plot them column vs column (e.g. df1$HV, df2$HV) - loop through the dataframe columns and plot them against each other in a scatter graph.

I've looked through 20+ questions asking similar things and can't figure it out - would appreciate some help on where to start.  Can I use lapply and plot or ggplot when they're two DFs?  Should I merge them first?

Comment: invisible(Map(plot,df1,df2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, I would indeed first rearrange into a list of plottable data frames before calling the plot command. I think that would especially be the way to go if you want to feed the `data` argument into `ggplot`. Something like:

```
plot_dfs <- lapply(names(df1),function(nm)data.frame(col1 = df1[,nm], col2 = df2[,nm]))
for (df in plot_dfs)plot(x = df[,"col1"], y = df[,"col2"])
```

or using ggplot:

```
for (df in plot_dfs){
  print(
  ggplot(data = df, aes(x=col1, y=col2)) +
  geom_point())}
```

and if you want to add the column names as plot titles, you can do:

```
for (idx in seq_along(plot_dfs)){
  print(
    ggplot(data = plot_dfs[[idx]], aes(x=col1, y=col2)) +
      ggtitle(names(df1)[idx]) +
      geom_point())}
```

Comment: Fantastic, is there a way to retain the column names so that when I plot them it doesn't just plot (col1, col2)?  I guess it'd have to be within the lapply call - with setNames()?

Comment: if you would retain the same (identical) colnames form both dfs, that would mean you would have to make a df with identical colnames (not possible) and a plot with identical axes labels (not informative). It would be better to add the matching colname as plot title and then label the axes as something like value_df1 and value_df2. I've added the code above.

Comment: Absolutely - that's that what wanted, thanks.  For a panel plot, will faceting work within the loop? I tried adding facet_wrap(~plot_dfs[[idx]]) but it doesn't like list objects

Comment: for faceting you need to combine everything to one df, where you add a variable saying from which column you added the data, so you can facet around that variable. If you want to arrange a list of plots (like you can generate now), you could have a look at ggarrange instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the columns like this:

```
for(col in 1:ncol(df1)){
  plot(df1[,col], df2[,col])
}
```

Make sure that both data frames have the same number of columns (and the order of the columns are the same) before running this.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one way to do it — loop over the column indices and create the plots one by one, adding them to a list and writing each one to a file:

```
library(ggplot2)

# create some data to plot 
df1 <- iris[, sapply(iris, is.numeric)]
df2 <- iris[sample(1:nrow(iris)), sapply(iris, is.numeric)]

# a list to catch each plot object 
plot_list <- vector(mode="list", length=ncol(df1))

for (idx in seq_along(df1)){

  plot_list[[idx]] <- ggplot2::qplot(df1[[idx]], df2[[idx]]) + 
    labs(title=names(df1)[idx])

  ggsave(filename=paste0(names(df1)[idx], ".pdf"), plot=plot_list[[idx]])
}
```

As you suggest in the question, you can also use `s/lapply()` with an anonymous function, e.g. like this (though here we're not storing the plots, just writing each one to disk):

```
lapply(seq_along(df1), function(idx){
  the_plot <- ggplot2::qplot(df1[[id]], df2[[idx]]) + labs(title=names(df1)[idx])
  ggsave(filename=paste0(names(df1)[idx], ".pdf"), plot=the_plot)
})
```

If you want to keep the list of plots (as in the `for`-loop example), just assign the `lapply()` to a variable (e.g. `plot_list`) and add line like `return(the_plot)` before closing the function.

There's tons of ways you could modify/adapt this approach, depending on what your objectives are.

Hope this helps ~~

*p.s.* if it's possible the columns won't be in the same order, it is better to loop over column *names* instead of column indices (i.e. use `for (colname in names(df1)){...` instead of `for (idx in seq_along(df1)){...`). You can use the same `[[` subsetting syntax with both names and indices.